# ListBox doesn't show complete items

Tags: xaml, listview, listbox

I have Expanders in a ListBox. If I now put a ListView into the last Expander, the ListView has exactly the size to show all of the items. This is so far what I want.
But now its not possible to scroll the ListBox down to the end of the ListView.

What do I have to do in order to allow the user to scroll the ListBox down to the end of the last item, which is the end of the ListView?

This is my simplified code:

```
<Window x:Class="ExpanderTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">

        <Expander Header="text">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Grid.Column="0">some text</Label>
                <Label Grid.Column="1">some text</Label>
            </Grid>
        </Expander>

        <Expander Header="Buttons">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Button Grid.Row="0">Button1</Button>
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button>Button2</Button>
                    <Button>Button3</Button>
                    <Button>Button4</Button>
                    <Button>Button5</Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Expander>

        <Expander Header="Much Information" IsExpanded="True">
            <ListView>
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridView.Columns>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Variable" Width="160" />
                        </GridView.Columns>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
                <ListViewItem>Line 0</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Line 1</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Line 2</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Line 3</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Line 4</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Line 5</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Line 6</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Line 7</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Line 8</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Line 9</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Line 10</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Line 11</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Line 12</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Line 13</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Line 14</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Line 15</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Line 16</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Line 17</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Line 18</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Line 19</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Line 20</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Line 21</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Line 22</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Line 23</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Line 24</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Line 25</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Line 26</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Line 27</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Line 28</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Line 29</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Line 30</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Line 31</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Line 32</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Line 33</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Line 34</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Line 35</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Line 36</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Line 37</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Line 38</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Line 39</ListViewItem>
            </ListView>
        </Expander>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to put your Expanders into a StackPanel within a ScrollViewer instead of using a ListBox.

If you need to keep your outer ListBox you can disable the ScrollViewer on it, and wrap that ListBox within a ScrollViewer.

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel>

            <Expander Header="text">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Column="0">some text</Label>
                    <Label Grid.Column="1">some text</Label>
                </Grid>
            </Expander>

            <Expander Header="Buttons">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Button Grid.Row="0">Button1</Button>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button>Button2</Button>
                        <Button>Button3</Button>
                        <Button>Button4</Button>
                        <Button>Button5</Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </Expander>

            <Expander Header="Much Information" IsExpanded="True">
                <ListView>
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridView.Columns>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Variable" Width="160" />
                            </GridView.Columns>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                    <ListViewItem>Line 0</ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem>Line 1</ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem>Line 2</ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem>Line 3</ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem>Line 4</ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem>Line 5</ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem>Line 6</ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem>Line 7</ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem>Line 8</ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem>Line 9</ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem>Line 10</ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem>Line 11</ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem>Line 12</ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem>Line 13</ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem>Line 14</ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem>Line 15</ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem>Line 16</ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem>Line 17</ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem>Line 18</ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem>Line 19</ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem>Line 20</ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem>Line 21</ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem>Line 22</ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem>Line 23</ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem>Line 24</ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem>Line 25</ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem>Line 26</ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem>Line 27</ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem>Line 28</ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem>Line 29</ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem>Line 30</ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem>Line 31</ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem>Line 32</ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem>Line 33</ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem>Line 34</ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem>Line 35</ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem>Line 36</ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem>Line 37</ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem>Line 38</ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem>Line 39</ListViewItem>
                </ListView>
            </Expander>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```